# Zero-inflated/Hurdle Models Show Bad Fit - Any Alternatives?

Tags: r, regression, modeling, zero-inflation

I am trying to predict customers as a function of spend, company, product type and market demand. The purpose of this modelling is for understanding the causal impact of IVs and for accurate predictions.

I initially tried to fit a negative binomial regression. When I used the Dharma package to test the goodness of fit, I could see that it tested positive for zero-inflation.
As a result, I have now fit a zero-inflated model and a hurdle model, using negative binomial regression to predict positive counts in both cases.

`zeroinflnb <- zeroinfl(customers ~ log(spend)+company+product | log(spend) + company + product + market_demand, data=train, dist="negbin")`

`modelHurdle <- hurdle(log(customers) ~ log(spend)+log(market_demand)+company+product, dist = "negbin", zero.dist = "binomial", data = train)`

The rootograms for both models suggest that the models underpredict most count bins. These models are clearly not a good fit. I am a bit stuck as to what I could consider next. Are there  any suggestions? Are there any other distributions for the positive count that you would recommend looking at instead? I don't need the solution but any feedback on the direction I should be looking at next would be useful.

[image]

[image]